# Java Selenium : Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to get last span's style value from first and second li, using this code

```
String lastdeal = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'container')]//ul[1]/div/li/div/span[7]")).getAttribute("style");
```

below is my html code and there are many div tag before class container.

it is showing unable to locate error.

Please let me know what i am missing

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="index__game-stats__list">
       ...
    </ul>
    <ul class="index__game-stats__table" style="height: 637px;">
        <li style="cursor: auto;">...</li>
        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; flex-direction: column;">
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,915,829</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:38</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000025</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35897 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35898 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35900 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35901 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35902 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">31.80</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(147, 204, 88);">0.00000011</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,913,519</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:37</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000025</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35881 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35882 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35884 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35885 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35886 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">7.56</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(147, 204, 88);">0.00000011</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,911,707</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:37</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000050</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35865 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35866 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35868 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35869 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35870 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">6.51</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(147, 204, 88);">0.00000023</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,909,553</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:37</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000025</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35849 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35850 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35852 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35853 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35854 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">81.56</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(255, 117, 145);">-0.00000025</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,906,424</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:37</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000100</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35833 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35834 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35836 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35837 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35838 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">20.96</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(147, 204, 88);">0.00000047</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,904,236</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:37</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000050</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35817 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35818 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35820 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35821 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35822 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">74.09</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(255, 117, 145);">-0.00000050</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,902,510</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:37</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000025</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35801 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35802 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35804 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35805 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35806 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">68.09</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(255, 117, 145);">-0.00000025</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,900,413</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:37</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000050</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35785 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35786 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35788 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35789 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35790 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">28.05</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(147, 204, 88);">0.00000023</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,898,624</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:37</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000025</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35769 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35770 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35772 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35773 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35774 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">98.12</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(255, 117, 145);">-0.00000025</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,874,142</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:36</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000050</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35753 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35754 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35756 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35757 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35758 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">56.81</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(147, 204, 88);">0.00000023</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,872,421</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:36</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000025</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35737 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35738 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35740 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35741 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35742 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">99.60</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(255, 117, 145);">-0.00000025</span></div>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;"><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">20,633,871,002</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">rikhisahu</span><span class="player-stats__hide">21:36</span><span class="player-stats__hide">0.00000025</span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35721 -->1.48<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35722 -->x<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide"><!-- react-text: 35724 -->&lt;<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35725 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 35726 -->67.00<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="player-stats__hide">6.45</span><span class="player-stats__show" style="color: rgb(147, 204, 88);">0.00000011</span></div>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

getting below error

[image]

Comment: ul[1] refers to the first ul for which source you have not mentioned. span[7] will return the 7th span in the containing div. There is no such span.

Comment: You've not said which `span` you seek to select.

Comment: @kjhughes i want last span's style value.

Comment: @Rik did you get your solution?

Comment: @AliAzam no sir.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning index for ul in your locator making problem, I guess.

Use Below locators

xpath

```
By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'container')]//ul/div/li/div/span[7]")
```

cssSelector

```
By.cssSelector("div.container ul li span:nth-child(7)")
```

Comment: getting this error "Exception in thread 'main' org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: div.container ul:nth-child(2) li span:nth-child(8)"

Answer (score 1):

First get all li elements and keep them on a WebElement list. Then find the span element and retrieve the style attribute. You can use like below:

```
List<WebElement> all_li_Elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.container > ul.index__game-stats__table > div > li"));
for (WebElement elem : all_li_Elements) {
    String lastdeal = elem.findElement(By.cssSelector("div > span:nth-child(8)")).getAttribute("style");
    //System.out.println(lastdeal);
}
```

You can easily get last span's style value from first and second li inside the for loop.

Comment: @Rik can you please try to implement my solution and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try keeping () in xpath whenever you are trying to find the nth element

```
(//div[@class='container']/ul[2]/div/li[1]/div/span)[7]
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the `style` attribute from the first `<li>` tag's last `<span>` tag you can use the following line of code :

```
String lastdeal = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='container']/ul[@class='index__game-stats__table']/div/li/div/span[last()]")).getAttribute("style");
```

Comment: `".//div[@class='container']/ul[@class='index__game-stats__table']/div/li/div/span"` this part is provided by you within the Question, I simply provided the logic of `last span` :)  Check out your path. Please update the question as per the actual formatted `HTML` for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//div[@class='container']/ul[2]/div/li[1]/div/span[7]
```

will select the `span` containing `31.80`.  Adjust the indices if it's another you seek to select.

---

**Update to address question update:**

> I am trying to get last span's style value from first and second li,
>   using this code

Then adjust the above XPath via `position()` and `last()` to meet your newly specified criteria:

```
//div[@class='container']/ul[2]/div/li[position()=1 or position()=2]/div/span[last()]/@style
```

returns

```
color: rgb(147, 204, 88);
color: rgb(147, 204, 88);
```

adjust `li[position()=1 or position()=2]` to just `li[1]` if you, say, only want the first `li`.

Comment: But this XPATH shows me error "Unable to locate element"

Comment: It is verified to work as described against the HTML you've posted.  If your actual HTML is different, update your question accordingly.   If not all elements are loaded at the time the XPath is evaluated, or if Selenium doesn't conform to the XPath spec, then you have a different problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying as per your suggestion, BTW there are many div tag before my code.

Comment: If you need help selecting the right `div`, you'll have to indicate something unique about the one you want.

Comment: before <div class="container"> tag there is <div class="index__game-stats "> tag and before this there is <div class="index"> tag and before that there are many other div tags

Comment: btw i am not understaning why it is showing me error while it is working for you  
WebElement lastdeal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='container']/ul[2]/div/li[position()=1 or position()=2]/div/span[last()]/@style"));
System.out.println("Last Deal Style :: "+lastdeal);

Comment: Take care to note what's being selected.  It doesn't seem right to call `findElement()` if the XPath is selecting multiple elements or attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Used firefox add-on "FirePath" for tracking right xpath and below is working code,

```
String lastdeal = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul[2]/div/li[1]/div/span[8]")).getAttribute("style");
```

BTW thank you all for your response...... /\